# Passing data back from Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

It has been some months that I've programmed for iOS, and want to finish my game with new features. Now when people play the game and lose they will see a "Game Over" view.

Now what I want is that people first see a view where they can use the bought credits they gotten and go back to the game with the `extra seconds or life`. But I'm not doing it on the right way.

Way I'm **trying** to do:

```
          - Save Me View (Segue)
Game view - 
          - Game Over View (Segue)
```

So, you lose, go automatically to the `save me` view, presses close and go to `game over` immediately. Otherwise use the NSUserDefaults that has been saved before showing the `Save Me` view.

So I'm using NSUserDefaults for saving previous game levels/points etc and that is not the right way of doing and the flow is getting complicated.

**Second try:**
I've tried it but I'm stuck at the last step. Because I'm using Segue's and delegates, I don't know how to make my GameView the delegate of the SaveView, while the protocols are already there.. I've followed this: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Now at step 6 it doesn't work because i'm using modal segue's with my UIViewControllers and no UINavigationControllers. I've this in my code atm:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SaveMe"]){

        SaveMeViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Here needs to come that GameView (This Class) is the delegate for SaveMeViewController. Tried vc.delegate = self; but this doesn't work.
        [self savePoints];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a delegate in the gave view that passes back how the game ended.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but I'm stuck at the last step. Because I'm using Segue's and delegates, I don't know how to make my GameView the delegate of the SaveView, while the protocols are already there.. I've followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers I'll edit my OP

Answer (score -1):

As my understanding use @property or delegate to pass data it will help you.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SaveMe"]) {
    SaveMeViewController * vc = segue.destinationViewController;
// create property in SaveMeViewController and access that property and pass values
    vc.property = value to assgin;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm doing, but I'm now creating a delegate to passing the data back, and for passing the data back, i need to figure out how to make GameView the delegate of SaveGame to get data back.